# State saved in vault without a notary

Tags: corda

Just ran my node directly:

java -jar corda.jar

But did not run the notary. Ran a flow that creates an output and calls FinalizeFlow. Completed successfully, then I was able to query the vault for the new state. This should not have happened since the Notary did not notarize the transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transaction is only sent to the notary for notarisation as part of `FinalityFlow` if:

- It has one or more inputs, and/or...
- It has a timestamp

If your transaction does not meet either of these conditions, it will not be sent to the notary, explaining the behaviour you saw above.